# How can heap allocation hurt hardware cache hit ratio?

Tags: c++, caching, heap-memory

I have done some tests to investigate the relation between heap allocations and hardware cache behaviour. Empirical results are enlightening but also likely to be misleading, especially between different platforms and complex/indeterministic use cases.

There are two scenarios I am interested in: bulk allocation (to implement a custom memory pool) or consequent allocations (trusting the os).

Below are two example allocation tests in C++

```
//Consequent allocations
for(auto i = 1000000000; i > 0; i--)
    int *ptr = new int(0);
    store_ptr_in_some_container(ptr);

//////////////////////////////////////

//Bulk allocation
int *ptr = new int[1000000000];
distribute_indices_to_owners(ptr, 1000000000);
```

My questions are these:

- When I iterate over all of them for a read only operation, how will cache
  memory in CPU will likely to partition itself?
- Despite empirical results (visible performance boost by bulk
  solution), what does happen when some other, relatively very small
  bulk allocation overrides cache from previous allocations?
- Is it reasonable to mix the two in order two avoid code bloat and maintain code readability?
- Where does `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::map`, `std::set` stand in these concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general purpose heap allocator has a difficult set of problems to solve.  It needs to ensure that released memory can be recycled, must support arbitrarily sized allocations and strongly avoid heap fragmentation.

This will always include *extra* overhead for each allocation, book-keeping that the allocator needs.  At a minimum it must store the size of the block so it can properly reclaim it when the allocation is released.  And almost always an offset or pointer to the next block in a heap segment, allocation sizes are typically larger than requested to avoid fragmentation problems.

This overhead of course affects cache efficiency, you can't help getting it into the L1 cache when the element is small, even though you never use it.  You have *zero* overhead for each array element when you allocate the array in one big gulp.  And you have a hard guarantee that each element is adjacent in memory so iterating the array sequentially is going to be as fast as the memory sub-system can support.

Not the case for the general purpose allocator, with such very small allocations the overhead is likely to be 100 to 200%.  And no guarantee for sequential access either when the program has been running for a while and array elements were reallocated.  Notably an operation that your big array cannot support so be careful that you don't automatically assume that allocating giant arrays that cannot be released for a long time is necessarily better.

So yes, in this artificial scenario is very likely you'll be ahead with the big array.

Scratch std::list from that quoted list of collection classes, it has very poor cache efficiency as the next element is typically at an entirely random place in memory.  std::vector is best, just an array under the hood.  std::map is usually done with a red-black tree, as good as can reasonably be done but the access pattern you use matters of course. Same for std::set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware that std::list literally stands in a completely different place. I kept it there for the sake of completeness. I'll mark this best in a few days unless a longer version appears.